# Combinator parser ~ also matches spaces

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying to parse string that follow the grammar `(x|y)+`. That is, the following should match:

```
x
y
xyyxyyxy
xyyxxy
and so on...
```

I have the following code:

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class XYs extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def E: Parser[Any] = (C ~ E) | C
  def C: Parser[Any] = "x" | "y"
}

object Main extends XYs {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    while (true) {
      println(parse(E, scala.io.StdIn.readLine()))
    }
  }
}
```

This parses the strings that should be matched, however it also matches some that should not be accepted, more precisely those with spaces.

`xyy xyx` works, as well as `xyyxy xyyx  xy`. Is there an easy solution to make the spaces not part of the parsing? Maybe a different "operator" than `~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.12/1.0.6/scala/util/parsing/combinator/RegexParsers.html), `skipWhitespace` is turned on by default for `RegexParsers`, and also for `JavaTokenParsers` which is subclass of `RegexParsers`.

> The parsing methods call the method skipWhitespace (defaults to true) and, if true, skip any whitespace before each parser is called.

You can just turn it off by overriding it.

```
class XYs extends JavaTokenParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false
  def E: Parser[Any] = (C ~ E) | C
  def C: Parser[Any] = "x" | "y"
}
```

Also you can use [rep1](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.12/1.0.6/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.html#rep1[T](p:=>Parsers.this.Parser[T]):Parsers.this.Parser[List[T]]) to match non empty repeats

```
class XYs extends JavaTokenParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false
  def E: Parser[Any] = rep1(C)
  def C: Parser[Any] = "x" | "y"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also had to change `parse` to `parseAll` or only the first segment would get parsed. Thanks!